# Updating Attributes of Class as Parameters Changes: How to Keep Brokerage Account Class up-to-date?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

How does one keep the attributes of an instance of a class up-to-date if the are changing moment to moment?

For example, I have defined a class describing my stock trading brokerage account balances.  I have defined a function which pings the brokerage API and returns a JSON object with the current status of various parameters.  The status of these parameters are then set as attributes of a given instance.

```
import json
import requests
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser   

class Account_Balances:
    def Account_Balances_Update():
    """Pings brokerage for current status of target account"""
        #set query args
        endpoint = parser.get('endpoint', 'brokerage') + 'user/balances'
        headers = {'Authorization': parser.get('account', 'Auth'), 'Accept': parser.get('message_format', 'accept_format')}

        #send query
        r = requests.get(endpoint, headers = headers)
        response = json.loads(r.text)
        return response        

    def __init__(self):

        self.response = self.Account_Balances_Update()
        self.parameterA = response['balances']['parameterA']
        self.parameterB = response['balances']['parameterB']
```

As it stands, this code sets the parameters at the moment the instance is created but they become static.

Presumably `parameterA` and `parameterB` are changing moment to moment so I need to keep them up-to-date for any given instance when requested. Updating the parameters requires rerunning the `Account_Balances_Update()` function.

What is the pythonic way to keep the attribute of a given instance of a class up to date in a fast moving environment like stock trading?

Comment: You probably want an update method that parses the results and assigns them. :)

Comment: You can simply update the values of the two parameters from inside `Account_Balances_Update` (which, by the way, needs to take at least one argument, `self`). The problem is that you need to make an instance of `Account_Balances`, then call its `Account_Balances_Update` method as often as you need to query the brokerage.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque

A quick vocab question: a method is a function within a class, right?

A quick syntax question: if I put an infinite loop within a class, the loop will continue to run as long as the instance is "alive", right?

Comment: Yes to your first question. For the second, it is yes but it depends how this is constructed. You could have an infinite loop triggered by a timer, a framework or a GUI listening to events.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just creating an update method?

```
class Account_Balances:
    @staticmethod
    def fetch():
        """Pings brokerage for current status of target account"""
        #set query args
        endpoint = parser.get('endpoint', 'brokerage') + 'user/balances'
        headers = {'Authorization': parser.get('account', 'Auth'), 'Accept': parser.get('message_format', 'accept_format')}

        #send query
        r = requests.get(endpoint, headers = headers)
        response = json.loads(r.text)
        balances = response['balances']

        return balances['parameterA'], balances['parameterB']

    def update(self):
        self.parameterA, self.parameterB = self.fetch()
```